# How do get the clicked object when using a Rails UJS "remote: true" ajax link?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I wanted to add a simple Star icon for favorites, however it became difficult when I wanted to use JS's `this` object to change the star icon from class `star` to `star-o` and vice versa.

I ended up just assigning a unique Id for each area that had a favorite icon...but this seemed overly difficult when dealing with pages that have dynamic content.

Is there anyway to reference the element you clicked while using `remote:true` and ajax through rails?

Comment: Instead of `ID`s you can use common `class` for all icons and also can you provide the code you tried

Comment: thank you.  I used ID because i might have many different star icons on the page that are associated with different objects.  I didn't want to change all of them each time someone clicks a star if it doesn't relate to the star they clicked.  In my `js.erb` file, I included jquery, `$(this).html('<%= escape_javascript render "new star icon" %>')`, or something similar

Comment: even with use of `class` you can change only selected `icon` and this is where `this` comes in play

Comment: Can't you reference the clicked element using the `event.target` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jQuery Rails fires a "ajax:success" event on the triggering element when you use `data-remote`:

```
$(".favorite").on("ajax:success",function(e, data, status, xhr){
  $(this).addClass('star-o').removeClass('star');
});
```

Adapted from [Working with JavaScript in Rails](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html#turbolinks).

Comment: not exactly what i was hoping for, but works for me. Thanks